# Kendo UI replaced my own classes on input fields, how do I get them back?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-mvc

I added a kendo UI MVC library, I had to update my MVC to the latest version (5.3.6) in order to make it all function...

but now when I run my application, the `Html.editorFor` contains only a single `class` `k-textbox` (which are `kendo UI` `classes`) even though I am adding the `class` `form-control` to it.

This `editorFor`

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.leverancier.leveranciernaam, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control disabled" } })
```

creates this Html:

```
<input class="k-textbox" data-val="true" data-val-length="Het veld naam moet een tekenreeks met een maximumlengte van 255 zijn." data-val-length-max="255" id="leverancier_leveranciernaam" name="leverancier.leveranciernaam" value="Bauerfeind">
```

so where's my `form-control` `class`?

**EDIT**

the application used to be an Asp.Net mvc 5 app. but in order for kendo to work I had to convert it to a Telerik Application.

Comment: Kendo adds some templates to \Shared\EditorTemplates for string, datetime, etc. I wonder if @Html.Kendo.TextBoxFor is overriding your class? Try Html.TextBoxFor instead of EditorFor.

Comment: Hi @SteveGreene, I thought so too. so I excluded them from my project but still it happens. I've also tried commenting out the scripts and styles but still all my textboxes contain none of the classes I told them to have. yet they just contain "k-textbox"

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but I wanted to confirm @SteveGreene's suggestion that templates could be the culprit here. @FllnAngl tried excluding the EditorTemplates from the project. Thank you both for putting me on the right path.

I had the same issue and not only removed the Views\Shared\EditorTemplates folder from my MVC project but also deleted the `*.cshtml` files in that folder. This solved my problem completely.

The Telerik UI for MVC, using the Editor Templates, was silently replacing the `@Html.EditorFor` with `@Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor` and therefore in my views was replacing the css class `form-control` with `k-textbox`, which affected input width.